# Is it possible to serialize a single property of a class?

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a class and I want to serialize just a single property of that class, is this possible?

So Say I have just a property of a class that is a Dictionary   and I just want to serialize that, not the whole class.

```
public class myClass{

string blah;

int blahblah;

Dictionary<Object, Object> ntDictionary;

}
```

INSTEAD of creating a separate class like this

```
[Serializable]
public class ObjectToSerialize : ISerializable
{
    private MyProperty _property;

    public MyProperty Property
    {
        get { return this._property; }
        set { this._property= value; }
    }

    public ObjectToSerialize()
    {
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: If you want to get the whole class back but just keep one property then add the [IgnoreDataMember] attribute to everything you don't want to serialize. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx

Comment: @ChrisKdon I just want the property, why do I have to serialize/deserialize the containing class.

Comment: You don't - just write the value to whatever target you are writing to.  Serialization is intended to convey the structure AND value of the data.  If all you want is a single value, you don't need to formally serialize anything.

Comment: @erotavlas If you just want the property why don't you just send the property? `XmlSerializer.Serialize(myClass.MyProp)`. (also you don't need to implement `ISerializable` if all of your members are serializeable, just adding the attribute is enough (Dictionary may or may not be serializeable, depending on the serialization you are using, for example it works fine for `DataContractSerializer`, does not work for `XmlSerializer`))

Comment: I agree with ScottChamberlain and dodexahedron from the sounds of it you just want to save the single value somewhere. This really isn't serialization in the traditional sense. Just write out the value directly to whatever format you want (text, xml, json, etc. )

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ok so I can do something like this?             BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bFormatter.Serialize(stream, anyType); Where anyType can be anything? Even string, int or some collection?

Comment: @erotavlas yes, but `BinaryFormatter` should only be used for IPC communication within the same machine, not for off machine communication or saving to persistant storage. It is extremely touchy about versions of referenced assemblies. When communicating between machines or saving information to the disk if all of the dll's are not exactly the same versions it will not work when you try to deserialize. So a windows update could cause all of your save files to not be readable. Use a 3rd party library like ProtoBuf.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Tag each property that you don't want automatically serialized with the `[NonSerialized()]` tag.

```
[Serializable()]
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Property1 {get; set;}

    [NonSerialized()]
    public int Property2 {get; set;}
}
```

Only Property1 will serialize from that class.

Comment: But doesn't it serialize the whole SomeClass with just that one property?  When I deserialize I just want the property, not the whole class

Comment: What kind of serialization are you doing - binary, text, json, etc?  Just write the property out manually if all you really want is just the value.

Comment: I think it would be binary, since my Dictionary contains keys and values that are objects.

Comment: That has no bearing on what type of serialization you're doing.  What are you writing the serialized data to?

Comment: hard disk, to persist a collection of values for a period of time

Comment: Then you get to choose how you do this.  If all you're doing is serializing the dictionary, save yourself a lot of time and effort and use something like JSON.Net and serialize the data out as JSON with a single function call.  Binary will not be human-readable and also will be non-portable (or difficult to port) if you change things.